# Update only Minor version in SharePoint when updating via CAML

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am using CAML to update a sharepoint list.  It is part of a service that runs nightly.  The update is causing a major version update every time it runs.  It would be nice if I could only change the minor version seeing that my just updating some fields based on the age of the item.

Is there anything I can add to the Method XML to make it only do a minor version change?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain how you do the update (web service, custom code, etc).

If you have versionining enabled, an update / check-in will result in a minor version.

Otherwise, if you want to update without triggering a new version, you can use `.SystemUpdate(false)` on the SPListem object to silently do an update without triggering a new version.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought it was implied when I said CAML that I was updating through the web service.  You can't use SystemUpdate through CAML.  For some reason the updates through the web service are causing major updates, not minor.

Comment: That's what I guess afterward re-reading your question and the method xml reference. What's your versioning settings on the list ? Are minor versions enabled or only major ? If you update manually a list item, can you check it in with a minor version number or will any update result in a major version ?